# Could not resolve domain name in curl

Tags: php-curl

I am writing the code below:

```
$data = array(
"client_id"=>"test_id",
"secret"=>"test_secret",
"public_token"=>"test,fidelity,connected");
// $string = http_build_query($data);
$string = json_encode($data);
// echo $string;

//initialize session
$ch=curl_init("https://sandbox.plaid.com/item/public_token/exchange");

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
//execute session
$exchangeToken = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
```

It gives me an error:

> {
>   
> "display_message": null,
>   
> "error_code": "INVALID_FIELD",
>   
> "error_message": "client_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string", 
>   
> "error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST", 
>   
> "request_id": "9o4pA" 
>   
> }

Stuck in this issue for a long time.

Comment: This isn't a problem with CURL, or with PHP for that matter. The error message is there: "client_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string". I assume you're not really sending "test_id" and whatever you're really sending is wrong. Also, what does any of this have to do with the title, "Could not resolve domain name"?

Comment: I used invalid client_id and secret, thats the reason it was showing "Could not resolve domain name". Got the solution, Thanku :)